# Getting unknown React Hydration failed error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
import { RichText } from "@graphcms/rich-text-react-renderer";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import Prism from "prismjs";
import "prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers";
import "prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css";
import "prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.css";

export default function Demo({ posts }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, []);
  return (
    <section className="prose m-auto">
      <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
      <RichText
        content={posts.content.json}
        renderers={{
          code_block: ({ children }) => {
            return (
              <pre className="line-numbers language-none">
                <code>{children}</code>
              </pre>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const endPoint =
    "https://randomenpoint.com/api";
  const slug = "random slug";
  const query = gql`
    query ($slug: String!) {
      posts(where: { slug: $slug }) {
        id
        publishedAt
        createdAt
        slug
        title
        updatedAt
        content {
          json
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  const client = new GraphQLClient(endPoint);
  const { posts } = await client.request(query, { slug });
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};
```

On my above code, when I'm adding the `line numbers` className inside `pre` tag I'm getting hydration error, what's wrong here? But without extra className inside `pre` tag, my code works fine. But it returns a normal code block in the browser. I want to use prismjs for styling. I'm using Nextjs,GraphCMS and tailwindCSS